# ng-options default value requires double click to select a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sql-server

I have created a select box using `ng-options`, which gets a pre-selected value from database.

#### My HTML:

```html
<h3>Process:</h3>
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-options="p.procid as p.procname for p in processes track by p.procid" 
        ng-model="processSelected">
  <option value="">-- choose an option --</option>
</select>
```

#### My controller:

```
$scope.processSelected = $scope.processes[2];
```

Now, it shows me in select box as `MyProcess1`, `MyProcess2`, `MyProcess3` and so on. For example, if default value was `MyProcess3`, and I want to choose `MyProcess1` process, the select box gets blank. When I click second time on `MyProcess1`, it selects it. I did not find any reason for this double click.

Please advise me how can I get it to select in single click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are overcomplicating your query for `ng-options`. Firstly, `track by p.procid` is used in `ng-repeat` to remove duplicates, which `<select>` doesn't care about. Secondly, your `p.procid as p.procname` breaks the logic, since it doesn't makes much sense.

Overall your code should be changed to `ng-options="p.procname for p in processes"`

Here is a working demo (without backend requests):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.processes = [{
      "procid": 1,
      "procname": "AAA"
    },
    {
      "procid": 3,
      "procname": "BBB"
    },
    {
      "procid": 4,
      "procname": "CCC"
    },
    {
      "procid": 2,
      "procname": "DDD"
    },
  ];
  $scope.processSelected = $scope.processes[2];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <h3>Process:</h3>
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="p.procname for p in processes" ng-model="processSelected">
      <option value="">-- choose an option --</option>
    </select>
    <p ng-show="processSelected">Selected: {{processSelected}}</p>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Aleksey Solovey. It was exactly the solution.